MQ-2 gas sensor problem: built and flashed code but serial has nothing in it
i'm trying to read the mq2 gas sensor using IADC, i took most of the code from this
https://github.com/SiliconLabs/peripheral_examples/blob/5a7d32d3bd903d79fab7b3cee2996c2d53a64a4b/series2/iadc/iadc_single_interrupt/src/main_single_interrupt.c.
somehow when i build and flash to the board (BGM220P), it didnt output anything
here is my code (main.c), app.c has nothing
#include <stdio.h>
#include "em_device.h"
#include "em_chip.h"
#include "em_core.h"
#include "em_cmu.h"
#include "em_emu.h"
#include "em_iadc.h"
#include "em_gpio.h"
#include "app_log.h"

#define CLK_SRC_ADC_FREQ 10000000
#define CLK_ADC_FREQ 10000000

#define IADC_INPUT_0_PORT_PIN iadcPosInputPortBPin0
#define IADC_INPUT_0_BUS BBUSALLOC
#define IADC_INPUT_0_BUSALLOC GPIO_BBUSALLOC_BEVEN0_ADC0
#define EM2DEBUG 1

static volatile IADC_Result_t sample;
static volatile float singleResult;

void initIADC(void) {
    IADC_Init_t init = IADC_INIT_DEFAULT;
    IADC_AllConfigs_t initAllConfigs = IADC_ALLCONFIGS_DEFAULT;
    IADC_InitSingle_t initSingle = IADC_INITSINGLE_DEFAULT;
    IADC_SingleInput_t initSingleInput = IADC_SINGLEINPUT_DEFAULT;

    CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_IADC0, true);
    CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_GPIO, true);

    IADC_reset(IADC0);
    CMU_ClockSelectSet(cmuClock_IADCCLK, cmuSelect_FSRCO);  // FSRCO - 20MHz

    init.warmup = iadcWarmupKeepWarm;
    init.srcClkPrescale = IADC_calcSrcClkPrescale(IADC0, CLK_SRC_ADC_FREQ, 0);

    initAllConfigs.configs[0].reference = iadcCfgReferenceVddx;
    initAllConfigs.configs[0].vRef = 5000;
    initAllConfigs.configs[0].adcClkPrescale = IADC_calcAdcClkPrescale(IADC0, CLK_ADC_FREQ, 0, iadcCfgModeNormal, init.srcClkPrescale);
    initSingleInput.posInput = IADC_INPUT_0_PORT_PIN;
    initSingleInput.negInput = iadcNegInputGnd;

    GPIO->BBUSALLOC |= GPIO_BBUSALLOC_BEVEN0_ADC0;

    IADC_init(IADC0, &init, &initAllConfigs);
    IADC_initSingle(IADC0, &initSingle, &initSingleInput);

    IADC_clearInt(IADC0, _IADC_IF_MASK);
    IADC_enableInt(IADC0, IADC_IEN_SINGLEDONE);

    NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(IADC_IRQn);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(IADC_IRQn);
}

void IADC_IRQHandler(void) {
    uint32_t flags = IADC_getInt(IADC0);

    sample = IADC_pullSingleFifoResult(IADC0);
    singleResult = (sample.data * 5.0) / 0xFFF;

    app_log("data: %.2f V\n", singleResult);

    IADC_clearInt(IADC0, flags);
}

int main(void) {
    CHIP_Init();
    initIADC();

    #ifdef EM2DEBUG
    EMU->CTRL_SET = EMU_CTRL_EM2DBGEN;
    #endif

    while (1) {
        IADC_command(IADC0, iadcCmdStartSingle);
        IADC_IRQHandler();
        CORE_DECLARE_IRQ_STATE;
        CORE_ENTER_CRITICAL();
        EMU_EnterEM2(true);
        CORE_EXIT_CRITICAL();
    }
}

i'm connecting my MQ-2 A0 pin to pin B0, GND to GND and VCC to 5V
thank you for supporting
i'm using simplicity studio, and my board is BGM220PC22HNA with gecko 4.4.3 SDK
i tried to follow the example IADC interrupt code above from silicon labs github but it didnt work

Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite C forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Is noted above, this isn't really a question, just a problem that you're having. However, you've made very significant changes compared to the reference code. You don't seem to be using IADC_IRQHandler as an interrupt handler, rather calling it directly. Also, have you checked that it's safe to print to the log in an interrupt (if that function was being treated as an interrupt handler)? The reference code doesn't show that being done.
